# Connecting an iPod being used as a Drive to a computer without iTunes

Tags: usb, itunes, ipod, mode

I have enabled disk mode on my iPod Classic which allows me to put normal files on it through windows Explorer.
I need to be able to transfer some files onto a computer at school which may or may not be internet enabled.
My question is will I be able to connect the iPod to the school computers that don't have iTunes installed and transfer the files off or are the drivers needed to do this included in the iTunes software.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you stored files on ipod like in external drive you will be able to retrieve them back, unless there are no drivers on your school computer to recognize your device

Answer (score 0):

Windows should automatically install drivers, and then you can browse your iPod under My Computer.